# Specify output filename with PutFile processor

Tags: apache-nifi

**Background**

I have a workflow that uses a `FetchFile` processor, some intermediary processors (e.g. `RouteOnAttribute`, `HashContent`, etc.), and then a `PutFile` processor.

Throughout it all, the content is not being manipulated.

**Issue/Problem**

The `PutFile` processor is saving files using a timestamp, NOT the original filename.

**Question**

How can I either:

1. Get the `PutFile` processor to use the original filename? **or**
2. Specify the filename that the `PutFile` processor will use?

Comment: You can check the part of "Reads Attributes" in the manual
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFile/index.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `PutFile` processor will save the content in a file with the filename based on the `filename` attribute on the flowfile. You can use an `UpdateAttribute` processor to provide whatever value you like for this attribute.

`GetFile` will read the original filename of the file on disk into this attribute, but because `FetchFile` expects the filename as an incoming attribute on the flowfile, it does not write the value back as an attribute.